# BUG in PHP 7.0.11, FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE

Tags: php, linux, web-services, networking, syntax-error

```
var_dump(filter_var('10.1.1.1', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE));
```

prints (in **PHP 7.0.11**):

```
bool(false)
```

But according the documentation is should print:

```
string(8) "10.1.1.1"
```

> PHPDOC: FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE
>   http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php
>
> Fails validation for the following reserved IPv4 ranges: 0.0.0.0/8,
>   169.254.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8 and 240.0.0.0/4.
>
> Fails validation for the following reserved IPv6 ranges: ::1/128,
>   ::/128, ::ffff:0:0/96 and fe80::/10.

**Is this a bug or am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10.1.1.1` *is* a [reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4). This was a breaking change introduced with [#1954](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1954). It will be fixed with [#2113](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2113).

Comment: But it is not even consistent across version https://3v4l.org/DONMm#v5625 . So it should filter all reserved / not public routed IP addresses? How can I update the PHP Doc?